# Using True and False to select items to print

Tags: loops, excel, checkbox, vba

I have a workbook that contains rows of information that needs to printed to a seperate worksheet in excel.  I am trying to utilize a checkbox to indicate which items need to print and which items need to be skipped.  The checkbox is located in column "A" and once checked and the macro ran, I want it to pick up the data in each cell of that particular row, transfer it a seperate worksheet (form), prompt and save the worksheet to pdf, clear the form, and then return to the main worksheet to continue until all rows have been checked.  However, right now, my code is only looping through the very first "TRUE" statement and not continuing to the rest.  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = False Then
        Else
            If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = True Then
                Call PrintWO
            Else
            End If
            Do Until ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = 10
                MsgBox "Nothing Selected to Print"
                Exit Do
                Exit Sub
            Loop
        End If
    Next i
    ErrHandler:
End Sub
```

Comment: if you downvote please leave a comment on why so the questioner can learn from any mistakes made

Comment: You should debug through your code. Put in some line breaks in and step through each line, then once you see what you code is doing, you can ask yourself "why is my code running that way" and identify mistakes on individual lines.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you got hammered with two down votes, but still...

Your problem is twofold. First:

```
Do Until ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value = 10
```

You can never have a checkbox value which = 10; it'll be either True, False or null, not an integer. Consequently that Do loop will never end since the check box can never be that value.

I think what you actually want is a Boolean flag to track whether any calls were made to PrintWO (set it to True if that block is executed), and if none were, THEN display that message AFTER your For block is completed.

Second, rarely should you have an error handler which does nothing. It should at least display what the error. My original thought was that your code would throw an error on the line quoted above; apparently it won't, but nor will that Do Until end which means that I'd imagine that either you end up killing the process or it crashes.